# Is there a way for isort to automatically detect firstparty vs thirdparty modules in a codebase with multiple standalone packages?

Tags: python, isort

In the `project` codebase, there are multiple standalone packages in a folder titled `plugins`, and each package is in its own folder which has a `setup.py` file in it, and the project itself is a python package with its own `setup.py` file.

I have two folders, `project/project` and `plugins/myplugin_one/project_plugins/myplugin_one`, that I need to be considered `first_party` and `third_party` when appropriate. For example, inside `plugins/myplugin_one/project_plugins/myplugin_one`, there's a file `config.py` with this code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Any, Dict, List, Optional

# First Party
from project.core.config_store import ConfigStore
```

The import `from project.core.config_store import ConfigStore` is being treated as a `first_party` import, but should be considered as a `third_party` import because the file resides in `plugins/myplugin_one/project_plugins/myplugin_one` and `myplugin_one` is a standalone package (`first_party`), while `project` is `third_party` in this context.

Similarly, for any imports residing in files inside `project/project`, `project/project` should be considered `first_party` and importing from `plugins/myplugin_one/project_plugins/myplugin_one` should be considered `third_party`.

The `sections` order for the project should be:

```
sections=
    FUTURE
    STDLIB
    THIRDPARTY
    FIRSTPARTY
    LOCALFOLDER
```

This is an upgrade from isort 4 to isort 5.4.2, so default sections are no longer `first_party` but `third_party` and `__init__.py` is not skipped by default.

This is my `isort.cfg` file:

```
[settings]
multi_line_output=3
include_trailing_comma=True
force_grid_wrap=0
use_parentheses=True
float_to_top = true
line_length=88
ensure_newline_before_comments=True
sections=
    FUTURE
    STDLIB
    THIRDPARTY
    FIRSTPARTY
    LOCALFOLDER
import_heading_stdlib=Standard Library
import_heading_firstparty=First Party
import_heading_thirdparty=Third Party
import_heading_localfolder=Local Folder
known_first_party=project,project_plugins
known_local_folder=build_helpers,tests
src_paths=
skip=
    __init__.py
```

Answer (score 1):

As said in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72115001/648044) answer you can use [multiple config](https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/config_files.html#supporting-multiple-config-files-in-single-isort-run) files.
I'll write some details as links can become broken.

I think you can simply use an isort config file under `plugins/` folder where you set `project` as [thirdparty](https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/options.html#known-third-party).

###### plugins/.isort.cfg

```
[settings]
known_third_party=project
```

In this case make sure to launch isort with the following option `isort --resolve-all-configs .`

If you want to check which config file is used you can add the `--verbose` option.

Answer (score 0):

isort provides support to treat certain packages as first or third party packages. This is done via [options](https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/options.html#known-third-party) in the config file. In your case it depends on the working directory which packages should be treated as first or third party packages. isort has [support to specify multiple config files](https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/config_files.html#supporting-multiple-config-files-in-single-isort-run) that are located in different directories. Though this approach is not fully automatic as the config files have to be specified.